# Match and Move batch Job

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a DOS batch job to review two different directories, identify files with like first six characters, and then move both the matched files to a third directory.  I'm getting a syntax error on the following code.  Any suggestions?

File 1:

```
set CopyCount=0


for %%f in (??????*.tif) do call ..\MatchMove1.bat %%f

cd ..

if %CopyCount%==0 goto end

ECHO %date%-%time% %CopyCount% "Matched and Copied" >> MatchMove.log
ECHO %date%-%time% "**************************************************" >> MatchMove.log

echo %CopyCount%

:end
```

File 2(MatchMove1)

```
set xFile=%1
set pFile=%xFile:~0,6%

cd..

if not exist "Copy3_Certificates_tiff\%Pfile%*.tif"  PAUSE goto end

copy "Copy4_Working_Documents\%pfile%*.tif" "Copy5_Cert_WorkDoc_Match"
copy "Copy3_Certificates_tiff\%pfile%*.tif" "Copy5_Cert_WorkDoc_Match"

rename "Copy4_Working_Documents\%xFile%" "%xFile%*.cpy"
rename "Copy3_Certificates_tiff\%pfile%*.tif" "%pfile%*.tif.cpy"

ECHO %date%-%time% "Files starting with "%pfile%" copied" >> ..\MatchMove.log

set /a CopyCount =%CopyCount%+1

:end
```

Comment: Can you post the error message and the command you invoked?

Comment: You asked for suggestions.  I suggest dropping a really horrible programming language (DOS batch), and using a sensible pattern matching language like perl.

Comment: Side note: Don't put spaces around the equals for `set`. The line `set /a CopyCount =%CopyCount%+1` will likely not do what you want. You can shorten it anyway to `set CopyCount+=1` (note that there is *no* space before the equals sign. Otherwise the variable would have the space included in its name.

Comment: @gary: Not really helping, imho ;-)

Comment: I'm getting:

'..\MatchMove1.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: The problem is that when you CALL another batch script, things done there (like CD and SET) affect the caller. If you were to add SETLOCAL, then the changes would be isloated to that script. You should, however, place an ENDLOCAL before the updating of CopyCount in order to make sure THAT change is propagated to the parent script.

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm getting: '..\MatchMove1.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file
```

This suggests that it can't find MatchMove1.bat, is it in the parent folder of the folder from where you started the process?

Comment: I'm a dope. No it's not! Thanks. It's still very in-ellegant code, and not running the way it should, but I think I can resolve the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kCind of problems I would put your two .BATs in a single file, using the `CALL :label` syntax.  See `HELP CALL`.

Also, for your `SET` commands to properly work, you need to make sure you have **enabled delayed expansion**. See the `HELP SET` for an explanation.

Insert this line

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

as the first line of your batch file.

and use `!CopyCount!` instead of `%CopyCount%` to get the environment variable.